# SPICE - How model body for EMI in a EEG system

Tags: spice, model, eeg

I was wondering how can I model the patient body in a EEG system to perform some simulation analisys. I started from [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa188/sbaa188.pdf) article which explains the coupling between the body and the EMI and the successive common mode voltage calculation.
Now I'd like to perform a simulation keeping in consideration the coupling of the body whit the EMI source (in particular the coupling between the two ground, the earth and the system one).

I tried whit this circuit (keep in mind the figure 5 in the article linked above)

[image]

but i don't know ho to model the coupling between the two grounds. Can anyone explain if it's possible? How Can I model correctly the patient's body?

Answer (score 0):

View the body as a square meter of conductive material, placed 1 meter above a conductive concrete floor.

Use the formula for capacitance, suitable for parallel-plate modeling and to get an approximate answer for many other topologies

C = 8.89e-12 Farad/Meter * air=1 * Area/Distance

For the 1 meter cube we just described, your C is 8.89pF